# Calling invalidateAuthToken doesn't seem to invalidate the auth token

Tags: android, accountmanager

I'm interacting with a REST service and when I get a 401 error I call `AccountManager.invalidateAuthToken` with my account type and the token I'm trying to invalidate, but nothing happens. I call `getAuthToken` right after `invalidateAuthToken` and I just get back the invalid token.